# List of content types posted/commented by users I follow

Tags: 7, views, flags, users

I'm running a D7 system Where users can follow each other using 'Follow' flag on user's profile.

Now I've been assigned a task to come up with a view where I can have a list of content posted/commented by people I follow.

I tried so many ways but no luck.

Comment: Are you using the Flag Follow module? Hearbeat running good? If not, how did you create the follow flag? Just a custom field?

Comment: Are you looking for the content "types", or the actual "nodes" with these content types? Also, can you enhance your question to provide more details about the "so many ways" you tried. That may help to provide you an accurate answer ...

Comment: @LauroSollero, I'm using normal 'Flag' which is then attached to 'user' entity type.User profile is laid out using panels.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, my D7 system has quite a few content types like news, blog, galleries and so on. What I want is a list of all of the nodes which were published or commented by the people I follow keeping in mind 'follow' is  flag on user profile.

Comment: Did you try this solution https://www.drupal.org/node/1580762 ?

Comment: @Andrew thanks for your recommendation, the node bit is easy its actual comments giving me hard time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've achieved this with the help of contextual filter `content: nid` and then using custom php which is below

```
 global $user;
$flag_items = flag_get_flag_flagging_data('Your_flag_name');
foreach($flag_items as $flag_item){
 if($flag_item->uid == $user->uid){
   $uids[] = $flag_item->entity_id;
 }
}
$nids = '';
$result = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('nid'))
    ->condition('uid', $uids, 'IN')
    ->execute();
while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
  $nids .= $record['nid'] . '+';
}

$result = db_select('comment', 'c')
    ->fields('c', array('nid'))
    ->condition('uid', $uids, 'IN')
    ->execute();
while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
  $nids .= $record['nid'] . '+';
}
$nids = trim($nids, '+');

return $nids;
```

Answer (score 2):

Humm, I couldn't find a way to easily put them all together (comments and nodes authored by the users followed) but could create separate views.

For nodes created is easier:
Create a new View, change from Show Content to Show Users and in the Relationship add a Flags: User flag, choose your flag and Current user.

For comments created:
Create a new View, select Show Comments. In the Relationship add Comment: author to expose the Authors ID, select require this relationship. Add new Relationship, this time look for Flag: User flag, select the author's relationship created before and your flag.

As stated before, you might get all the content together but I couldn't get it in any easy way.